# Difficulty to find the pre-images of a pair of hash result such that given $a,b$, $H(x_1)=aH(x_2)+b$?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, provable-security

Suppose given fix values $a,b$, how difficult to find a pair of sha256 pre-images $x_1,x_2$ such that $H(x_2)=aH(x_1)+b$? How difficult to find 4 hash pre-images $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ such that $\dfrac{H(x_2)-a}{H(x_1)+b}=\dfrac{H(x_3)-a}{H(x_4)+b}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Case 1:** Assuming $\mathbb{F}_2^n.$ The only scalar constants you can have in characteristic $2$ to are $0$ or $1$? So, you need to define multiplication for quantities in $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ for this to be non trivial.

Let $n=256.$ For any  vectors $b\in \mathbb{F}_2^n,$ your first equation with scalar $a$ is equivalent to

- $H(x_2)=b$ if $a=0,$ which takes $O(2^n)$ work (preimage problem).
- $H(x_1)\oplus H(x_2)=b,$ which takes $O(2^{n/2})$ work (collision problem).

As for your second equation, it reduces to a quadratic relation which doesn't look meaningful in this context since the multiplication has to be defined for it to make sense.

One can use $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ as a representation for $\mathbb{F}_2^n,$ under some canonical basis, maybe a self dual basis, but more *cryptographic* justification for what you seem to be attempting needs to be provided for such an operation, given that solving quadratics is no easier than solving linear equations.

**Case 2:** (Thanks to @kelalaka) If you mean to take $\mathbb{Z}_{2^{256}},$ then one might guess that if the hash function is strong, the $a-$multiple $a H(x_1):=H_a(x_1)$ can itself be modeled as a random function and you are now solving a generalized collision problem between two random functions
$$
H(x_2)-H_a(x_1)=b
$$
which again should have complexity $O(2^{n/2}).$

For the second question things are trickier. Firstly there are zero divisors in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{2^{256}},$ and you should not divide but cross multiply and consider
$$
(H(x_2)-a)(H(x_4)+b)=(H(x_1)-a)(H(x_3)+b)
$$
Let $u_i$ be the largest exponent of $2$ which divides the value $H(x_i)- c_i$ modulo $2^{256}$  where $c_1=c_3=a$ and $c_2=c_4=-b$. *If $u_1+u_3\geq 256,$ then we need to have either $H(x_2)=a,$ or $H(x_4)=-b,$ (either happen with probability $2^{-256}$ or $u_2+u_4\geq 256,$ for this equation to have a solution.*

Again, modeling these translated hashes as pseudorandom functions $Pr[u_i\geq k]=2^{-k},$ for $0\leq k\leq 255.$ For example, $Pr[u_i\geq 1]=1/2,$ which happens if the LSB of the hash output is 0.

Using this, one can derive actual probabilities for these equations to hold, based on the argument in italics.

Comment: aha, that might be. Let's see if he clarifies.

Comment: have a look at what I wrote, don't have much time to do more right now.